# Is it possible to send a calendar file (.ics) as part of an MMS via the Twilio programmable API?

Tags: java, twilio, icalendar, twilio-api, mms

I'm still pretty new to using the Twilio SMS/MMS programmable API.  I've had pretty good success with send basic SMS via the Twilio Java library.  But, I have a client that is interested in sending a general calendar appointment to some of their end users as a kind of save-the-date that the end user could conveniently add to their calendar without having to create an appointment from scratch.  This is not intended to be a meeting invite that would be tracking acceptance of users.  I've went down the path of creating an API that serves up an .ics file and setting a media URL to that endpoint when send an MMS via the the Twilio API.  I was able to successfully attach the file.  But, the .ics file will not open on my device (iPhone) and I, therefore, cannot add the event to my calendar.  Has anybody else tried this?  Could this be related to the file type not being explicitly supported by the Twilio API?  Would a incorrectly formatted .ics file cause this (I can share the construction of the file if needed)?  Thank you in advance.

***UPDATE***
To give a little more context, I'm going to include the API code:

```
@Path("/calendar")
public class CalendarEventAPI {

    @GET
    @Path("/event/{eventName}")
    public Response getCalendarEvent() {
        return Response.ok(buildCalendarEvent())
            .header("Content-Type", "text/calendar")
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"cal.ics\"")
            .build();
    }

    private String buildCalendarEvent() {
        return "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n" + 
                "VERSION:2.0\r\n" + 
                "PRODID:-//ABC Corporation//My Product//EN\r\n" + 
                "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n" + 
                "DTSTART:20191003T110000\r\n" + 
                "DTEND:20191003T140000\r\n" + 
                "LOCATION:Unknown\r\n" + 
                "TRANSP:OPAQUE\r\n" + 
                "UID:b642020d-3370-4696-8378-2e42d3efb224@example.com\r\n" + 
                "DTSTAMP:20190923T200519Z\r\n" + 
                "SUMMARY:Awesomeness\r\n" + 
                "DESCRIPTION:Awesome Stuff is happening!\r\n" + 
                "END:VEVENT\r\n" + 
                "END:VCALENDAR";
    }

}
```

Comment: So, I updated my header for Content-Type to be the proper casing and I stripped my calendar event data down to be a little more basic and can now get the file as part of the MMS and am able to open the file.  But, I can't add it to my calendar as a part of the MMS.  When I go to the endpoint directly via the browser, my phone (iPhone) can download and open the file, as well as gives me the option to Add to Calendar.

Comment: This seems like good progress. Sadly I'm not in the US and can't receive MMS from Twilio numbers, so I can't help test this any more myself. Just to check, can you MMS a calendar event to yourself from a phone? And what is the experience there?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This isn't something I've tried. The [accepted MIME types for MMS include `text/calendar`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types), so if you are serving the .ics file with that `Content-Type` correctly then it should work.

Are you able to open the file on your iOS device by visiting the URL? Can you validate the .ics file with an [online validator like this one](https://icalendar.org/validator.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @philnash.  I started up the service and used the online .ics validator that you supplied and it claimed success/no errors.  I have updated my original post with the source.  I believe I'm setting the Content-Type header correctly (unless the header name is case sensitive).  I'll google that.